# Can sunlight be simulated?

Tags: sunlight, germination

Can you use certain consumer-lights for simulating sunlight?

I know not any light will suffice, since they do not contain the same wavelengths as sunlight and whatnot.

Or are there special lights available for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[some general news](http://translate.google.es/translate?hl=en&sl=it&u=http://www.borda.it/schede/lucecaldafredda.htm&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dtemperatura%2Bcolore%2Bluce%2Bsolare%26hl%3Den%26biw%3D1047%26bih%3D860&sa=X&ei=ZYhZUb33HKny7Aa3hIGIAg&ved=0CD4Q7gEwAQ)

There are bulbs that mimic the solar spectrum that is used by plants (which varies approximately from 400 to 700 nm).
Lamps with these characteristics are mainly some fluorescent and some metal halide lamps, which have a high color rendering index value (Ra> 90). For example the lamps Philips TLD (930, 940, 950, 965) and the lamps Osram Lumilux Deluxe (12, 22, 32, 72) or the HQI ...
Or you can use the Sonlight AGRO 600W HPS like, but there are also Philips (AGRO 400W, SON-T Plus 400W/600W) and Sylvania (grolux 400W or 600W) ... you just need to properly evaluate how much you want to spend .... both of electricity that of bulb.